# Reference on simplicial homotopy theories

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

I read a very user-friendly and modern treatment of closed model categories in *Homotopy theories and model categories* by Dwyer and Spalinski and I liked it very much. This basically covers Chapter I of Quillen's *Homotopical Algebra*.

I was wondering if there are modern treatments of chapter II, i.e. **are there any user-friendly modern exposition on simplicial homotopy theory**? The more similar to Dwyer and Spalinski's the better. Thank you!

Comment: Should this question be made Community Wiki ? In addition to Goerss and Jardine's "Simplicial homotopy theory", you might want to have a look in chapter 3 of Hovey's book "Model categories".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Goerrs and Jardine's [Simplicial Homotopy Theory](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~topology/books/goerss-jardine.pdf).